# Borked upgrade from 1.3 to 2.3

Tags: updating

I'm trying to upgrade an Craft site from 1.3 to 2.3 and have gotten into a broken state.

The update button failed, so I tried a manual update. This noted that I needed at least version 2.1, which I then downloaded and tried. It throws the following error and reverts:

*CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'edition' in 'field list'*

When I revert back to 1.3 the admin screen is now blank.

The relevant versions/schema info:

- Version: 1.3, Build: 2486, Schema: 1.3.15 (blank login)
- Version: 2.1, Build: 2570, Schema: 2.1.2 (SQL error)
- Version: 2.3, Craft Build: 2635, Schema: 2.3.4 (desired version)

The craft_info table shows that I'm running 1.3. The site is up, but I can't access the backend.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In between borked update attempts, are you restoring the database to the pre-update state? By default, Craft will create a database backup and place it in the `craft/storage/backups` folder during an update that you can use.

If you look at your `craft/storage/runtime/logs` files you'll be able to 1) see the error that originally happened to cause the failed update and 2) see the error that's preventing the CP from loading.

Comment: Thanks Brad, I managed to get one of the old SQL files to work, then the auto-update did two separate upgrades and everything is groovy.